# Failure to authenticate with Artifactory using Python Poetry

Tags: python, authentication, python-poetry

I'm using the Poetry package manager for Python for the first time. I have a private package stored on our enterprise Artifactory instance.

I followed the very simple instructions for how to declare a package source and credentials for it.

There are basically two ways to declare creds.

1. Storing them in Poetry's internal config
2. Storing them in environment variables

Neither worked.

I was able to auth to the Artifactory `/simple/` endpoint in a browser with my creds.
I was able to auth when I embedded the creds in the URL directly (not acceptable for storage in version control).
I was able install the package using `pip`.

I bothered a colleague for a while and remembered what it was like to be a noob Python programmer...

Long story short, see my answer below for the... answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently no one else on the entire internet has had this problem so...

It turned out I had an existing `~/.netrc` file that already had creds for our Artifactory instance. I had used it for a prior project from years ago and it had different, no longer valid creds in it.

No amount verbose output would tell me that this file was the source of the failing creds.

Changing the value to valid creds solved the problem.

Removing the value in `~/.netrc` (e.g. Changing the machine name to something different) and then storing internal to Poetry (`poetry config http-basic.foo <username> <password>`) also worked.

---

The moral of the story is: If you're ever getting weird errors with auth over a network despite using credentials that you **know** are valid, check your `~/.netrc` file. **Who knows** what uses that thing?!?! (Someone probably knows. )